# Compiler error on onNewIntent() for Kotlin activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Please see this [image]

Even though I added super statement, still it is telling me to add same thing!
Compiler: "Overriding method should call super.onNewIntent"

I also tried to put in first line, still the same error.

I tried to clean, invalidate cache also but same error. I'm able to run the project, but why this is coming, since this is a important part of project, I want to be sure that nothing gets break.

Comment: @Jorn I already tried and already mentioned in question also, same issue

Comment: But it builds correctly right ?

Comment: @ItzDavi yes it is building

Answer (score 1):

This is [a reported bug in Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244088936).